# Joining across multiple relations for a collection

Tags: model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Given the following gist: https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/6674488eb4fbd7a45671

`Users have and belong to many Applications.`

`Applications have many PushMessages.`

`PushMessages belong to one Application.`

I'd like to be able to get all PushMessages for every Application that the User is related to.

Looking at `QueryCode.php` in the gist, what would I have to change to get things working?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the PushMessage class to query them.

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$pushMessages = PushMessage::whereIn('application_id', $user->applications()->lists('id'));
```

Comment: Is there no way to use the ORM's collections to query it?  This seems like basically writing manual SQL...

Comment: Also, you're issuing two queries where this could all be done with one according to my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
PushMessage::leftJoin(Application::getTable(), Application::getTable().'.id', '=', PushMessage::getTable().'.application_id')->leftJoin(...)->where(Application::getTable().'.user_id','=',1)->select(PushMessage::getTable().'.*')->get();
```

Eloquent really just offloads method calls to the fluent query builder. Although, i'd suggest wrapping this specific query in a method, or putting it in a repository

Comment: Again, this seems like a hack.  If you look at my example query, I'm using eager loading to load in the relations...  I find it hard to believe there's no way to access this data...

Comment: This is not a hack. Eloquent really just tries to be a thin layer between sql and Objects . The query i have written is not complete, because i didn't want to write down all the joins. UPDATE: I took a look at your QueryCode.php , I think its the "StudlyCaps" thats preventing your relations from being eager loaded.